# Event.target.value is not working in my React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to fetch the API to display tv series from tvmaze but whenever i used e.target.value to fetch all the tv series it doesn't fetch any value. However when i'm just fetching only one episode like Game of Thrones it works perfectly. Kindly review my code and help me to debug my code. i'll provide more code if anyone wants. Thanks

```
    class Series extends Component {
        state = {    

            series: [],

            seriesName: '',

            isFetching: false
        }

              onSeriesInputChange = e => {
                  this.setState({ seriesName: e.target.value, isFetching: true});

                  fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${e.target.value}')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => this.setState({ series: json, isFetching: false}));   
    }
    ``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're trying to use ${e.target.value} as part of ES6's string template literals, you need to use the grave accent `` quotes, not single quotes ' '

Comment: hey man..thanksssssss it works perfectly now

Comment: no problem! glad it helped!